# Finding the frequencies of repeated values in Rstudio with duplicate unique values

Tags: r

I am currently working on a problem that requires me to extract all maxima and find the frequency of time it spends in that maxima before finding a new one. There is a rare case that sometimes is met when the maxima occurs at the same value at another time point and my frequency is counting the total of said maxima, but not the total of that new occurrence.

For example, the desired outcome from the peaks vector would be the freq vector

```
peaks = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,5,5,5,1,1,1)
freq = [3,3,2,3,3]
```

However my code produces `freq = [8,3,3]`  so when I replicate the frequencies to have them side by side it doesnt work as im doing `rep_freqs = rep(freq, times = freq)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `rle`

```
rle(peaks)$lengths
```

Comment: @akrun Yes, exactly, Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is `diff` with `table`

```
table(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(peaks) != 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table`'s `rleid` :

```
as.integer(table(data.table::rleid(peaks)))
#[1] 3 3 2 3 3
```